# Image quality in intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, mediastore

My program uses ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE intent to capture images.

When added to the parameter MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT camera automatically opens with the quality 5 megapixel (my phone is a milestone 2).
Image example
http://www.zacs.com.br/2_add_extra_output.png

If the parameter is not added MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT opens with the camera quality 1.2 megapixel.
Image example
http://www.zacs.com.br/1_not_extra_output.png

In the two examples you press the menu button the camera's setup menu is not displayed.

Is there any way to configure this?

thanks,

Evandro

Comment: There is similar question: [Camera intent with resolution parameters in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980996/camera-intent-with-resolution-parameters-in-android)
The answer is it depends very much on device. And probably it's better to go with own implementation of image capturing if you need more control.

Comment: And I believe for capturing is used resolution, which was previously selected in camera app.