# how to specify size of photo in camera capture in android phone

Tags: android

I want that my camera to capture specified size of images, I am opening camera in my application using Camera Intent in android. please give me guide lnes

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to set setPictureSize on the camera parameters

```
Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 70);
parameters.setPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG);
parameters.setPictureSize(2048, 1232);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Check this:
[Camera intent with resolution parameters in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980996/camera-intent-with-resolution-parameters-in-android)

Comment: How to set parameters if camera is opening using intent

Answer (score 0):

Use Camera.Size to specify the dimensions for pictures:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Size.html

Possibly, you may need to crop the image to be captured by your camera if not fitted:

[How to crop an image in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846338/how-to-crop-an-image-in-android)